# Adding a column based on another column R data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have two data tables in R:

```
#install.packages("data.table")
library(data.table)
dt1 <- data.table(Num = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5))
dt2 <- data.table(Num = 1:5, Letter = c('A','B','C','D','E'))
```

I want to add a column to the first data table based on dt2, so it will have two columns:

```
dt1 <- dt1[,Letter := "THIS WILL CONTAIN AN 'A' FOR EVERY '1', 'B' FOR EVERY '2', ETC"]
```

The second data table serves as a key for which letter corresponds to which number in another data table.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
setkey(dt1, Num)
setkey(dt2, Num)
dt2[dt1]
    Num Letter
 1:   1      A
 2:   1      A
 3:   1      A
 4:   2      B
 5:   2      B
```

Answer (score 3):

We can `join` with using `on`

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.6+
dt2[dt1, on ="Num"]
```

For creating the "Letter" column in "dt1", we don't need the "dt2"

```
dt1[, Letter:= LETTERS[Num]]
```

Comment: What if the second data table doesn't have the column "Num" for reference, just the letters?

Comment: @abbas786, In that case, you can convert the `LETTERS` to `numbers i.e. `as.numeric(factor(LETTERS))` gets the sequence i.e. `dt2[, Num := as.numeric(factor(Letter))]` and then join or even without using `dt2` (in the update)

Comment: I'm trying not to be too specific because I was hoping to figure it out eventually. I can't do that because for my data sets the letters are actually character IDs that correspond to specific numbers. So each 1 would be "AFFY1" and each 2 would have "AFFY2". Also I need to add to the data table that already has the numbers, not the numbers to the letters.

Comment: @abbas786 In that case, you can use `as.numeric(factor(` approach.  If the elements doesn't correspond to any pattern, specify the `levels` and `labels` in that.

Comment: @abbas786 [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 2):

The disadvantage of the methods in the other answers is that `dt1` is not updated and the result is only printed to the console. You can update `dt1` by reference as follows:

```
dt1[dt2, lttr := Letter, on="Num"]
```

This gives the following result:

```
> dt1
    Num lttr
 1:   1    A
 2:   1    A
 3:   1    A
 4:   2    B
 5:   2    B
 6:   2    B
 7:   2    B
 8:   3    C
 9:   3    C
10:   3    C
11:   3    C
12:   3    C
13:   3    C
14:   4    D
15:   4    D
16:   4    D
17:   4    D
18:   4    D
19:   4    D
20:   4    D
21:   5    E
22:   5    E
23:   5    E
```