# Print values associated with levels

Tags: r

I have this piece of code:

```
data <- read.csv("small.csv",header=TRUE, sep=",")
data$normal = as.character(data$normal)
data$normal[data$normal == "ipsweep"] = "3"
data$normal[data$normal == "portsweep"] = "3"
data$normal[data$normal == "nmap"] = "3"
data$normal[data$normal == "satan"] = "3"
data$normal[data$normal == "buffer_overflow"] = "5"
data$normal[data$normal == "loadmodule"] = "5"
data$normal[data$normal == "perl"] = "5"
data$normal[data$normal == "rootkit"] = "5"
data$normal[data$normal == "back"] = "1"
data$normal[data$normal == "land"] = "1"
data$normal[data$normal == "neptune"] = "1"
data$normal[data$normal == "pod"] = "1"
data$normal[data$normal == "smurf"] = "1"
data$normal[data$normal == "teardrop"] = "1"
data$normal[data$normal == "ftp_write"] = "4"
data$normal[data$normal == "guess_passwd"] = "4"
data$normal[data$normal == "imap"] = "4"
data$normal[data$normal == "multihop"] = "4"
data$normal[data$normal == "phf"] = "4"
data$normal[data$normal == "spy"] = "4"
data$normal[data$normal == "warezclient"] = "4"
data$normal[data$normal == "warezmaster"] = "4"
data$normal[data$normal == "normal"] = "2"
data = data[!(data$normal=="0.00"),]
data = data[!(data$normal==""),]
data$normal = factor(data$normal)

When I run: `data$normal`, it gives the following output

   [1] 2 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 4 1 1 2 3 2 2 1 1 2 2 1 2 1 2 2 2 3 1 2 3 2 2 2 1 2 1 1 1 2 2 2 1 1 2 4 1 2 1 1 2 2 2 3 1 1
```

Now I would like to print the values associated with the levels in every column but it is returning all `FALSE` or `0`. For example:

```
x<-data[normal=="neptune",]
```

How can I print every column whose row value is `neptune` but not `1`?

Comment: When I run `data$normal` it gives me `Error in data$normal : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable`. You should construct an example that makes your problem reproducible.

Comment: *"I have this piece of code"* Ahhhh! Why do you have that piece of code! Delete it, make a look-up table (which is essentially what you ask for, "the values associated with the levels") and do a `merge` or something instead of that monstrosity.

Comment: And realize that, if you do things the way you did, you just overwrite values and **don't** preserve the mappings. Once you set `"ipsweep"` and `"portsweep"` and `"nmap"` all to `"3"`, there is no going back! All you have is a bunch of rows of value `"3"` and the code you used to get there.

Comment: @Gregor, any hints on how i can do that dear?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8433523/creating-a-new-variable-from-a-lookup-table, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34757584/adding-a-column-based-on-another-column-r-data-table, and many others

Comment: For as many values as you have, if it's manual, I would usually handjam it into an Excel spreadsheet or Google Sheet, save it as a CSV, and then read it into R. If there were only a few values I would just do `lookup = data.frame(key = c("ipsweep", "portsweep", "nmap", ...), value = c(3, 3, 3, ...))`

Comment: Sometimes you can get a head start using `dput()`. Assuming it's a factor to start, use `dput(levels(your_data$your_column))` to get a vector with all the current values, and then you can `cbind` it or `name` it with another vector of what you want the values to be.

Answer (score 2):

If you dig around that GitHub repository a bit more, you'll find a couple of other useful csv files. [The first](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/defcom17/NSL_KDD/master/Attack%20Types.csv) lists the attack types, which names that match the names in the small training dataset. [The second](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/defcom17/NSL_KDD/master/Field%20Names.csv) lists the field names, which are nowhere to be seen in the main csv file.

The attack type csv was probably designed for exactly what you're trying to do. It's a lookup table that associates an attack "type" with each attack attack "name". You can merge this with your main dataset as follows.

```
# Base url
u <- 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/defcom17/NSL_KDD/master'

# Read in the field names table
nm <- read.csv(file.path(u, 'Field%20Names.csv'), 
               header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

# Read in the attack types table
attacks <- read.csv(file.path(u, 'Attack%20Types.csv'), 
                    header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, 
                    col.names=c('name', 'type'))

# Read in the main dataset
d <- read.csv(file.path(u, 'Small%20Training%20Set.csv'), 
              header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

# Assign the field names to the main dataset. This is really optional.
names(d) <- nm[, 1]

# There were a couple of names missing. 
# One is obvious, while the other seems irrelevant for now.
names(d)[42:43] <- c('name', 'code')

# By default, merge() merges on fields that the datasets have in common (i.e., "name").
d2 <- merge(d, attacks)

head(d2)
##     name duration protocol_type  service flag src_bytes dst_bytes land
## 1 normal        0           tcp ftp_data   SF       491         0    0
## 2 normal        0           udp    other   SF       146         0    0
## 3 normal      240           tcp     http   SF       328       275    0
## 4 normal        0           tcp     http   SF       232      8153    0
## 5 normal        0           tcp     http   SF       199       420    0
## 6 normal        0           udp domain_u   SF        46        46    0
##   wrong_fragment urgent hot num_failed_logins logged_in num_compromised
## 1              0      0   0                 0         0               0
## 2              0      0   0                 0         0               0
## 3              0      0   0                 0         1               0
## 4              0      0   0                 0         1               0
## 5              0      0   0                 0         1               0
## 6              0      0   0                 0         0               0
##   root_shell su_attempted num_root num_file_creations num_shells num_access_files
## 1          0            0        0                  0          0                0
## 2          0            0        0                  0          0                0
## 3          0            0        0                  0          0                0
## 4          0            0        0                  0          0                0
## 5          0            0        0                  0          0                0
## 6          0            0        0                  0          0                0
##   num_outbound_cmds is_host_login is_guest_login count srv_count serror_rate
## 1                 0             0              0     2         2         0.0
## 2                 0             0              0    13         1         0.0
## 3                 0             0              0     9        10         0.0
## 4                 0             0              0     5         5         0.2
## 5                 0             0              0    30        32         0.0
## 6                 0             0              0    96       178         0.0
##   srv_serror_rate rerror_rate srv_rerror_rate same_srv_rate diff_srv_rate
## 1             0.0           0             0.0          1.00          0.00
## 2             0.0           0             0.0          0.08          0.15
## 3             0.0           0             0.1          1.00          0.00
## 4             0.2           0             0.0          1.00          0.00
## 5             0.0           0             0.0          1.00          0.00
## 6             0.0           0             0.0          1.00          0.00
##   srv_diff_host_rate dst_host_count dst_host_srv_count dst_host_same_srv_rate
## 1               0.00            150                 25                   0.17
## 2               0.00            255                  1                   0.00
## 3               0.20            255                250                   0.98
## 4               0.00             30                255                   1.00
## 5               0.09            255                255                   1.00
## 6               0.02            255                254                   1.00
##   dst_host_diff_srv_rate dst_host_same_src_port_rate dst_host_srv_diff_host_rate
## 1                   0.03                        0.17                        0.00
## 2                   0.60                        0.88                        0.00
## 3                   0.01                        0.00                        0.00
## 4                   0.00                        0.03                        0.04
## 5                   0.00                        0.00                        0.00
## 6                   0.01                        0.01                        0.00
##   dst_host_serror_rate dst_host_srv_serror_rate dst_host_rerror_rate
## 1                 0.00                     0.00                 0.05
## 2                 0.00                     0.00                 0.00
## 3                 0.00                     0.00                 0.00
## 4                 0.03                     0.01                 0.00
## 5                 0.00                     0.00                 0.00
## 6                 0.00                     0.00                 0.00
##   dst_host_srv_rerror_rate code   type
## 1                     0.00   20 normal
## 2                     0.00   15 normal
## 3                     0.00   21 normal
## 4                     0.01   21 normal
## 5                     0.00   21 normal
## 6                     0.00   18 normal
```

Note that the data have now been sorted by attack name.

To subset to the `neptune` attacks, you can use `subset`:

```
subset(d2, name=='neptune')
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure what you want to do, but if you want to use the character data later on, you cannot overwrite it with the (string) numbers. This would seem to be a better solution:

```
keys_values <- c("ipsweep" = 3, "portsweep" = 3, "nmap" = 3, "satan" = 3, "buffer_overflow" = 5, 
                 "loadmodule" = 5, "perl" = 5, "rootkit" = 5, "back" = 1, "land" = 1, "neptune" = 1, 
                 "pod" = 1, "smurf" = 1, "teardrop" = 1, "ftp_write" = 4, "guess_passwd" = 4, "imap" = 4, 
                 "multihop" = 4, "phf" = 4, "spy" = 4, "warezclient" = 4, "warezmaster" = 4, "normal" = 2)

data$normal <- as.character(data$normal)
data$normal_value <- keys_values[data$normal]
data <- data[data$normal != "0.00" & data$normal != "", ]
data$normal <- factor(data$normal)

x <- data[data$normal == "neptune", ]
```

Comment: @Brown You overwrite the character data in your original code. That's why you cannot access it. In my suggested solution, you create a new column that stores the new values.